# How could I use checkbox and search?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a datagridview and 3 checkbox name :chkfilename, chkfiledate, chkexdate.
[image]

And I use condition search with each checkbox. Ex:

```
if (chkFilename.Checked)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from TBLBackupFile where DestinationFileName like '%" + txtFileName.Text + "%' or SourceFileName like '%" + txtFileName.Text + "%'";
            //cmd.CommandText = "Select * from TBLBackupFile";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

-and condition search for chkfiledate :

```
if (chkFileDate.Checked)
        {
            DateTime fromdate = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text);
            DateTime todate = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker2.Text);


            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.CommandText = "select * from TBLBackupFile where SourceFileDate>='" + fromdate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00") + "' and SourceFileDate <= '" + todate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd 23:59:59") + "'";
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            da1.Fill(dt1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
        }
```

-How could I use condition search for 2 checkbox if I set :

```
if (chkFilename.Checked && chkFileDate.Checked)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you need?

Comment: I checked  condition search by click checkbox near label, you see?. I click every single checkbox and click button search. It done !. But I dont know how to search with 2 checkbox ?

Comment: you want to detect if two checkbox are checked when you press 'Search'?

Comment: @nachogsiri yes, could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var conditions = new List<string>();

if(chkFilename.Checked)
{
    conditions.Add(string.Format("DestinationFileName LIKE '%{0}%' OR SourceFileName LIKE '%{0}%'", txtFileName.Text));
}

if(chkFileDate.Checked)
{
    DateTime fromdate = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text);
    DateTime todate = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker2.Text);
    conditions.Add(string.Format("SourceFileDate>='{0:yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00}' AND SourceFileDate <= '{1:yyyy/MM/dd 23:59:59}'", fromdate, todate));
}

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    con.Close();

con.Open();
using(SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    var condition = "";
    if(conditions.Any())
        condition = string.Format("WHERE {0}", string.Join(" AND ", conditions.Select(c => "(" + c + ")")));
    cmd1.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM TBLBackupFile {0}", condition);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    da1.Fill(dt1);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to apply condition on the basis of checkbox check status. Here is one of the way which might be useful for you

```
string whrCond = "";
if (chkFilename.Checked)
{
    whrCond = "DestinationFileName like '%" + txtFileName.Text + "%' or SourceFileName like '%" + txtFileName.Text + "%'";
}
else if (chkFileDate.Checked)
{
    if(chkFilename.Checked)
        whrCond = whrCond + " AND "
    whrCond = whrCond + "SourceFileDate>='" + fromdate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00") + "' and SourceFileDate <= '" + todate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd 23:59:59") + "'";    
}
else if (chkexdate.Checked)
{
    if(chkFileDate.Checked || chkFilename.Checked)
        whrCond = whrCond + " AND "
    whrCond = whrCond + //Whatever your condition is 
}
else
{
    whrCond = "1 = 1";
}

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    con.Close();
}
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from TBLBackupFile where " + whrCond;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

**Note:** *I have not run the program so take it like the algo and not the solution*

Comment: thank you so much , your code is simple than me. but I get a trouble with syntax error and I resolved it :).